# Meaning Of High Variance With Few Components In PCA

Tags: pca

I am new to PCA and currently applying it to a dataset where each sample consists of 500 measurements points.

When applying PCA, the cumulative variance of the top 5 components is ~99%, which puzzles me.

1. Could this dataset be described with 5 variables while preserving almost all discriminative value?
2. What would this say about the dataset?
3. Could you expect similar performance in machine learning models for the raw and PCA data, since nearly al variance is preserved?